# How to place ejs in loops

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

People is an array of objects having firstName andlastName

<% for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) { %>

<%= firstName %> <%= lastName %>

<% } %>

Why end of %> is after loop { brakcet.
What is the need of ejs in end bracket of loop <% }%>

Comment: Why end of %> is after loop opening  bracket it could be there before bracket opening

Comment: This is to allow you to write HTML code in between your EJS template. Otherwise your HTML comes in between EJS. Hope that explains your query.

Comment: There is no upvote options yeah thanks